# Second Coroutine isn't working Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making 2D game and want to cause delay of about 3 sec after player's all lives ran out. I tried to implement Coroutine method before the scene start all over again but it doesn't work. 
I have already implemented Coroutine method for each time my player falls of a cliff and respawn back to its position. And it works like a charm.

```
public void Respawner()
{
    StartCoroutine("RespawnCoroutine");
}

// Coroutine  Delay of 2 sec for each time player Respawn
public IEnumerator RespawnCoroutine()
{
    classobj.gameObject.SetActive(false);   
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(respawnDelaySec);
    classobj.transform.position = classobj.respawnPoint;
    classobj.gameObject.SetActive(true);             
}

public void ReduceLives()
{
    if (lives <= 3 && lives >= 2)
    {
        lives--;
        live_text.text = "Remaining Live " + lives;
    }
    else 
    {
        StartCoroutine("RestartScene1");
    }  
}

public IEnumerable RestartScene1()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(RestartSceneDelaySec);
    SceneManager.LoadScene("demo2");
}
```

here is no error on console window but  `SceneManager.LoadScene("demo2")`; is never called and the player is respawning each time after i die and after 1 life remaining

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your second coroutine is..

You have mistakenly used "IEnumerable" instead "IEnumerator", make it change to "IEnumerator" and it will work..

Comment: lol i feel like an idiot now, thanks for helping me out sir. But there is one slight problem now, Respawn delay is set to 2 sec and Restart_scene set to 3 sec. When all lives run out the player respawn again for 1 sec and then the scene restarts again. which is kinda annoying i want it to completely pause or end scene when all lives run out. And then start scene again. Is there a code for pausing scene?

Comment: @EslaBaeny, I was sure that I checked that you used `IEnumerator` instead of `IEnumerator` apparently I checked only the first method, not the second. Please consider accepting this answer.

Comment: @EslaBaeny 
Accept this answer if it solved your issue.

For your 2nd question.
You can stop RespawnCoroutine when you run out of lives  and restart it when scene is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `SceneManager.LoadScene("demo2");` after `StartCoroutine("RestartScene1");`.

`StartCoroutine("RestartScene1");` this code you can say is an asynchronous code. It is called, and the execution of program keeps going forward (the execution does not await here). You should call the code you want to delay inside that Coroutine after `yield`ing.

Small exampel:

```
public void SomeFunction()
{
    StartCoroutine("RestartScene1");
    // The code here will **not** be delayed
}

public IEnumerable RestartScene1()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(RestartSceneDelaySec);
    // The code here will be delayed
}
```

Comment: so i declared `SceneManager.LoadScene("demo2");` inside
`public IEnumerable("RestartScene1");` after yield but that doesnt work either the game is stuck after 1 life remaining

Comment: @EslaBaeny, I am not sure what about your conditions. Please debug the game and check what is the state of your conditions, and is the code inside Coroutine being called?

Comment: i tried your code but that doesnt work.. game is stuck after 1 life remaining and the player is respawning again and again and the 'SceneManager.LoadScene("demo2");' is never called. I have written full code belowe in answer , please have a look

Comment: @EslaBaeny, are you sure that `StartCoroutine("RestartScene1");` is being called?

Comment: sory i have now edited my question, i think its 'StartCoroutine("RestartScene1");' being called... Do you recommend me to declare 'StartCoroutine("RestartScene1");'  inside some method and call the method inside else statement?

Comment: @EslaBaeny, it should be ok what you are doing. You have not answered me yet; are you sure that `StartCoroutine("RestartScene1");` is being called?

Comment: i am not clearly sure what you mean  but i have already initialized public 'IEnumerable RestartScene1()'  in my class and 'StartCoroutine("RestartScene1");' should start that if i am not wrong. 
Is that what you asking? Sorry if i  sound like an idiot. I am new to programming and learning alot of stuff.

Comment: @EslaBaeny, please debug the code, and set a break point on the line I mentioned, and tell if the debugger hits that break point.

Comment: i tried to debug code on visual studio but  it throwing error that class with library cant start as executable file than i selected code and selected debug text  ------ Discover test started ------
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00.0319819) ==========

Comment: am i doing it correctly? so for stupid noob questions

Comment: @EslaBaeny, sorry I can not understand what you mean

Comment: @Muhammed Lol i was using IEnumerable instead of IEnumerator inside declaration of my 2nd  coroutine. i.e  `public IEnumerable RestartScene1()` instead of  `public IEnumerator RestartScene1()`